# CREATE TABLE AS with PRIMARY KEY in one statement (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, create-table

**Is there a way to set the PRIMARY KEY in a single "CREATE TABLE AS" statement?**

Example - I would like the following to be written in 1 statement rather than 2:

```
 CREATE TABLE "new_table_name" AS SELECT a.uniquekey, a.some_value + b.some_value FROM "table_a" AS a, "table_b" AS b WHERE a.uniquekey=b.uniquekey;
 ALTER TABLE "new_table_name" ADD PRIMARY KEY (uniquekey);
```

Is there a better way of doing this in general (assume there are more than 2 tables, e.g. 10)?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

According to the manual: [create table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html) and [create table as](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtableas.html) you can either:

- *create table* with primary key first, and use *select into* later
- *create table as* first, and use *add primary key* later

But not both *create table as* with *primary key* - what you wanted.

Comment: Of the two options, creating the primary key (and its associated index) *after* data is loaded will probably be faster.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to create a new table with the same table structure of another table, you can do this in one statement (both creating a new table and setting the primary key) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_clone (
   LIKE mytable 
     INCLUDING defaults
     INCLUDING constraints
     INCLUDING indexes
);
```

Answer (score 2):

See the command below, it will create a new table with all the constraints and with no data. Worked in postgres 9.5

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <ClonedTableName>(like <OriginalTableName> including all)
```

Comment: This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no shorter way to create the table and the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

well in mysql ,both is possible in one command

the command is

```
create table new_tbl (PRIMARY KEY(`id`)) as select * from old_tbl;
```

where `id` is column with primary key of old_tbl

done...

Comment: Downvoted since this is mysql syntax, not postgres (per the question). And not possible in postgres.

Comment: well I have exact same problem in mysql at same time of question posted and I myself solved it with this command ,so i think this may be usefull to my friend here.(beside i am not allowed to comment yet,and thought that SQL syntax will be same for Postgre SQL,so i posted this as answer)   anyway thanks for exapnding my knowledge about postgre sql...

Comment: Upper vote, even if it was not the question it was useful for me ;)

Answer (score -6):

You may do this way

```
CREATE TABLE IOT (EMPID,ID,Name, CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY( ID,EMPID)) 
 ORGANIZATION INDEX NOLOGGING COMPRESS 1 PARALLEL 4
AS SELECT 1 as empid,2 id,'XYZ' Name FROM dual;
```

Comment: That's invalid for Postgres

Comment: Looks like Oracle syntax